# remove everything after first space on each line of this text file

Tags: php, file

In PHP, how can one edit a text file and save it so that everything after the first space is removed?

In other words, so that each line only has its first word?

For example, if the text file looked like this:

```
Adi NNP
Adia NNP
Adios NNP FW
Adios-Direct NNP
Adios-On NNP
Adios-Rena NNP
Adios-Trustful NNP
Adirondack NNP
Adirondacks NNPS
Adjoining VBG
Adjournment NN
```

after executing the script, the text file would look like this:

```
Adi
Adia
Adios
Adios-Direct
Adios-On
Adios-Rena
Adios-Trustful
Adirondack
Adirondacks
Adjoining
Adjournment
```

How I would approach this would be to open the file, read it in, and take each line and store it in an array. Then replace everything after the first space with nothing. And lastly, save the edited array to a new file.

Is there a better way to do it than that?

All I know how to do in the above method is everything except the last two tasks. I would do it like so:

```
$file = array();
$lines = file('file.txt');
foreach($lines as $line){
    array_push($file, $line);
}
// now travel through $file and replace everything after first space with nothing
// travel though $file again, but write each element as a new line in a .txt file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode()` to separate the line by spaces. Then you can immediately write the string back to a file, no second loop is required:

```
$file = array();
$lines = file('file.txt');

$new_file = fopen('new.txt', 'w+');
foreach($lines as $line){
    $bits = explode(' ', $line);
    fwrite($new_file, $bits[0] . PHP_EOL);
}

fclose($new_file);
```

Comment: I just tired this code and it is not writing a new file called new.txt. I don't know why. The logic / code seems solid. Here is teh code I am running: http://pastebin.com/0sYFc0JQ

Comment: are you sure that you have write permissions in that folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the same line: just replace `array_push($file, $line)` with...

```
$file[] = strtok($line, ' ');
```

It can be written even more compact with help of `array_map`:

```
$lines = array_map(function($line) {
  return strtok($line, ' ');
}, file('file.txt'));
```

... or you can write it back immediately, as shown in @hek2mgl answer.

Comment: Set `display_errors` on and show the error message itself. 500 is just a generic error code.

Comment: I'm getting a PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in edit.php on line 7, here is the contents of edit.php: http://pastebin.com/qMHuB0Pk

Comment: So you're using PHP 5.2... (sigh). Well, you can still use `array_map` - just move the definition of the function it uses outside (like shown [here](http://pastebin.com/5GMyCJWu)).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought I was running 5.3. I'm now running exactly what is in your pastebin and am getting no errors, but also the file isn't changing. Exactly what is in your past bin is [here](http://the-irf.com/edit.php) and the text file is in the same dir [here](http://the-irf.com/file.txt).

Comment: Are you writing the `$lines` back into that (or another) file? BTW, I've checked the file; what you're going to do with all these lines starting with non-letters?

Comment: No, I'm not writing $lines to a new file. How do I do that? I am going to delete those manually.

Comment: The easiest, I suppose, is just to use `file_put_contents('new_file.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));` - after that array was filled.

Comment: I'm getting an error. Do I have to change the permission on the dir to write to it? To what? 755? failed to open stream: Permission denied in edit.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass arrays entirely and do this with a simple [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
// Read in contents into a variable
$data = file_get_contents('input.txt');

// Drop the space and everything after on each line
$data = preg_replace('/ .*$/m', '', $data);

// Dump contents to file   (change this to input.txt if you want to overwrite the file)
file_put_contents('output.txt', $data);
```